# julia error: map is not defined on dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, julia

```
julia> hotcell2vocab = Dict([(cell, i-1+vocab_start)
                  for (i,cell)  in  enumerate(hotcell)]);

julia> vocab2hotcell = map(reverse, hotcell2vocab)
ERROR: map is not defined on dictionaries
```

`hotcell2vocab` is a `Dict` and is there a method that can reverse the key and the value in a `Dict`?

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
julia> d = Dict(i => i+10 for i in 1:5)
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 5 entries:
  4 => 14
  2 => 12
  3 => 13
  5 => 15
  1 => 11

julia> d_rev = Dict(b=>a for (a,b) in d)
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 5 entries:
  14 => 4
  13 => 3
  11 => 1
  15 => 5
  12 => 2
```

Of course this assumes that the values in your dictionary are unique.

Comment: Thanks! But is there anything wrong with the map function

Comment: `map` is explicitly disallowed for `Set` and `Dict` types. Probably you could try to define it but the problem is that those types do not guarantee iteration order and the question is what should be the type of return value of such `map`. Finally e.g. someone could want to map only values of `Dict` leaving keys intact.